# Does zookeeper work with equinox or only felix?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-zookeeper, equinox, apache-felix

I have been looking at a tutorial on Hadoop to get ZooKeeper working, but I'm not sure if it will work in a Equinox Framework or only Felix?

Any ideas?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work, I wonder?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Equinox to test, so if someone else answers with personal experience, mark theirs up. Lacking another answer though, yes, I'm fairly certain it does work. There's [a blog detailing](http://groglogs.blogspot.com/2012/02/ecf-remote-osgi-ds-declarative-services.html) some other services where the author states:

> For this example we will be using the Eclipse IDE for Java with the
>   ECF Remote Services Target Components  plug-in, the **Equinox
>   framework** and **ZooKeeper** as a service discovery provider.

This seems to indicate that both can be used together. I found several other examples when Googling things such as "using Equinox framework with Zookeeper" that indicated both could/were being used together.

Answer (score 0):

ZooKeeper itself does not require an OSGi container. But it works very well in Equinox. We use it in the Eclipse Gyrex project for clustering/coordination.

A ZooKeeper OSGi bundle is available from the Eclipse Orbit project (eg., the last R build):
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/